# How to set custom OleDb connection properties in ADO.NET?

Tags: ado.net, oledb, aceoledb

In COM ADO you can use the [**`Properties`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) collection to set custom properties on a [**`Connection`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), even after the connection is opened. Is there any equivalent for ADO.NET?

I need this to do some  operations on an Access database. The ACE OleDb provider (`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`) supports many of the same custom connection properties as the former `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider (see [Microsoft OleDb Provider for Jet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). A very important one when working with Microsoft Access is the `Jet OLEDB:Max Locks Per File` property. This property is only available *after* the connection is open. Including it in the connection string before opening the connection will raise an error:

> Could not find installable ISAM

I can accomplish this using COM interop to use the COM ADO Connection, but it would be nice if there was a native ADO.NET way to do this.